# Math functions in C

Tags: c, function, header

I am using Code::blocks to compile my first multiple source file, learned from "C Programming in easy steps" by Mike McGrath. Unfortunately my math functions seem to be having issues. Here's the header that contains the functions:

```
/* this header file contains utility functions */

int square(int x);       /* function prototypes */
int multiply(int x, int y);

int square(int x) 
{ 
return (x*x);
}

int multiply(int x, int y)
{
return (x*y);
}
```

The only function having the problem is "square()". It reads the input of "2" as "2293356" and outputs the square as "553755367"... What the heck?!?

Here's the menu.c file... There's menu.c, ops.c, calc.c, and utils.h. Abaov is the .h.
MENU.c
    include

```
void menu();

void menu()
{

    int num;
    printf("\n\tEnter the number of an operation:\n");
    printf("\t1. Square a number\n");
    printf("\t2. Multiply two numbers\n");
    printf("\t3. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    switch(num)
    {
    case 1 : getnum(); break;
    case 2 : getnums(); break;
    case 3 : return;
    }
}
```

Here's ops.c...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "utils.h"

void getnum();
void getnums();

void getnum()
{

    int num;
    printf("Enter an integer to be squared: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("%d squared is %d\n, num, square(num)");
    menu();
}

void getnums()
{

    int num1, num2;
    printf("Enter two numbers to be multiplied, ");
    printf("seperated by a space: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("%dx%d = %d\n", num1, num2, multiply(num1, num2));
    menu();

}
```

This is the last part of the program, calc.c,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    menu();
    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post your I/O statements.

Comment: The problem is not with your maths functions; it will be to do with your input/output routines.

Comment: Apart from your problem: Note that header files usually contain only declarations and no definitions, which are left to the source files.

Comment: @Nobody: Unless they're inline or static or both

Comment: @Michael: The code is good so far. Could you show GetNum and Getnums as well?

Comment: @Michael printf("%d squared is %d\n, num, square(num)"); Is this your real code since I think this will only print out square(num) instead of calling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square of **2293356** doesn't fit into `int` and therefore overflows which leads to undefined behavior! As to why it reads 2 as 2293356 cannot be answered without more code.

***Update:*** 
And here's your real error:

```
printf("%d squared is %d\n, num, square(num)");
```

should be

```
printf("%d squared is %d\n", num, square(num));
```

:)

Comment: Indeed.  But the OP says that he's giving it "2".

Comment: @Oli: I'll update my answer as soon as/if he updates the question

Comment: include <stdio.h>

void menu();

void menu()
{

    int num;
    printf("\n\tEnter the number of an operation:\n");
    printf("\t1. Square a number\n");
    printf("\t2. Multiply two numbers\n");
    printf("\t3. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    switch(num)
    {
    case 1 : getnum(); break;
    case 2 : getnums(); break;
    case 3 : return;
    }
}

Comment: @Michael: It's unreadable in a comment. Please edit your question instead.

Comment: @Michael: And please show code for GetNum and GetNums functions as well

Comment: @Armen: But in that case, where is square() called?

Comment: @Ziyao: It's not, but `printf()` leads to undefined behavior when less arguments are provided than `%`'s in the format string

Comment: @Armen I though the OP means his output is like "2293356 squared is 553755367"? Anyway, we could wait for him to reply:) Edit: Uh-oh, seems that you got it:)

Comment: @Ziyao: I suppose this solved his issue since he accepted this answer

Comment: LOL... The most important thing in every language... Proofreading. ;)

Comment: @Michael: printf and other functions with variadic argument lists are notoriously error-prone. That's why I like C++ :)

Comment: @Armen: The compiler should give a warning in this case, so *this* one isn't a good argument for using C++.

Comment: I plan to move up to C++ once I get the hang of C. I haven't touched programming since Q-Basic... :P

Comment: @Armen Your last comment is just non-sense. But I can't down vote comments. Plus, I doubt there wasn't a warning.

Comment: @sidyll: How could there be a warning?! Do you expect the compiler to look at the string (which can be dynamic, btw), count the number of `%`s in it and if number of further arguments is less than that issue a warning?!

Comment: @sibyll: I must say I am impressed. But still the format string could be runtime-generated. In this case no warning would be possible

Comment: @Sven and sybill: And I don't like C++ just for iostreams. I like it for all other features it has :)

Comment: While the compiler *might* generate a warning (which all current ones should do if the format is a string literal) they are not forced to do so, as Armen said in both the C90 `7.9.6.1` and the C99 `7.19.6.1` standards it is undefined behavior: `If there are insufﬁcient arguments for the format, the behavior is
undeﬁned`

Comment: @Sidyll: LOL! Now I'm very impressed :))) But you have to agree that the compiler treats standard functions specially. If I were to define my own function with variadic arguments, the compiler wouldn't be able to help detect errors, would it? :)

Comment: Hmm, to tell you the truth I don't know. We'd better wait the next lawyer or start testing.